# Creating a table gives me an invalid syntax error message

Tags: mysql

When using the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE stats 
(
  username varchar(12), 
  starting text, 
  ending text, 
  UNIQUE (username)
)
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE stats 
(
  username varchar(12), 
  starting text, 
  ending blob, 
  UNIQUE (username)
)
```

I get an error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'starting text, ending text, UNIQUE (username))' at line 1

Am I doing something wrong?  It worked perfectly fine before adding `ending text` inside the query.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, ajreal, forgot that's how they're supposed to look!

Comment: `starting` appears to be a reserved word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`starting` is a reserved word, therefore you need to write it like this:

```
`starting` text
```

Comment: Thanks! Would I need to use it for all queries? Such as: `mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO stats (username, starting, ending) VALUES ('$username', '$stats', '$stats')");`

Comment: yes, otherwise you will get complaints about it like the one above.

Answer (score 1):

`starting` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL; therefore you either should take a different one or enclose it in `backticks`.

```
CREATE TABLE stats 
(
  username varchar(12), 
  xyzstarting text, 
  ending text, 
  UNIQUE (username)
)
```

works for me.

Answer (score 1):

`starting` is a reserved keyword

```
CREATE TABLE stats 
(
  username varchar(12), 
  NotUsingStarting text, 
  ending text, 
  UNIQUE (username)
)
```